# Trying to create a lookup function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to create a dictionary using a list filled with tuples. Every tuple should be a pair, e.g. (word, description_of_said_word).
So far I have this:

```
banana = ("banana", "a yellow fruit")
orange = ("orange", "a orange fruit")
apple = ("apple", "a green fruit") 
my_list = [banana, orange, apple]

def lookup():
    word = raw_input("Word to lookup: ")
    print ("\n")
    n = my_list.index(word)
    x = my_list[n][0]
    y = my_list[n][1]
    if word == x:
       print x, ":", y, "\n"
    else:
       print("That word does not exist in the dictionary")
lookup()
```

When I write in banana I get an error saying, "ValueError: 'banana' is not in the list". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to loop through the list of tuples and compare the input word to the first item in each tuple. If it matches, then print and return. If it makes it through the whole list without finding a match, let the user know that word doesn't exist.

```
banana = ("banana", "a yellow fruit")
orange = ("orange", "a orange fruit")
apple = ("apple", "a green fruit") 
my_list = [banana, orange, apple]

def lookup():
    word = raw_input("Word to lookup: ")
    print ("\n")
    for fruit in my_list:
        if fruit[0] == word:
            print fruit[0], ":", fruit[1], "\n"
            return
    print("That word does not exist in the dictionary")
lookup()
```

Comment: How do I let the user know without letting it run through the loop?

Comment: Well if it find a match before it runs through the entire loop, it will print that one out as soon as it finds it and exit. There's no way to know if the word wasn't in the dictionary unless you run through the entire loop (or use a different structure, such as a dict, instead of a list of tuples).

Comment: I added a else statement that prints out "That word does not exist in the dictionary" in the loop. Is it okay if I put a break right after? So it doesnt print out the same message n amount of times?

Comment: If you put a break statement in your else clause it might exit the loop early, no? It only makes sense to print "that word does not exist in the dictionary" after it has looked through the whole dictionary.

Comment: Oh haha, silly me. I fixed it now. Thank you very much! You guys are a life saver! :D

Answer (score 1):

`"banana"` is not in `my_list`. `("banana","a yellow fruit")` is. These are different objects.

If you instead use `my_dict = dict([banana,orange,apple])` you will get an actual dictionary in which `"banana"` is a key and `my_dict["banana"]` will give you `"a yellow fruit"`.

Read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Oh alright, well that makes sense. How do I check just for the first elements in the tuples then? :)

Comment: The thing is I am not allowed to use a dictionary, only a list filled with tuples :/

Comment: Then there's no standard function that will do it AFAIK. Iterate through `my_list` with a for loop and find the index manually.

Comment: @Erik.E you probably want to make that *explicit* in your question then - at the moment it's not clear you want something *like a* dictionary but you must not use Python's builtin `dict` type. (I'm taking a guess the reason you've been given a list of 2-item tuples is that your *next* step is to be using this answer though!)